# Lovr only one display?

Tags: lua

I am using lovr and I do not use VR for it. I use it as a 3d render engine for lua. Because I don't use vr, it shows two displays instead of one. I will attach a screenshot. Or if this is not possible, does anyone recommend a good lua render engine? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31UZb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FAQ in the documentation](https://lovr.org/docs/FAQ):

> You can also set the t.modules.headset flag to false in lovr.conf to disable VR completely and develop a traditional 3D desktop application.

Comment: I have done this, but I don't know if I did it right. I could send the code if that will help?

Comment: I just realized that my lovr.conf(t) is not working

Comment: Nevermind I just found out why, I didn't put it in a conf.lua file, thanks for the help!

Comment: Any time! Glad you got it working.